# Is VM resolving expensive? MVVM Autofac

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We have a WPF MVVM application, we are using Autofac as our DI IOC container. We register viewmodels and resolve them at runtime.

I realized that all the constructors of all our viewmodels and subviewmodels and subsubviewmodels run at the start of the program. As you'd expect i guess.

Our vms usually have a need to get data from the database, so we are using a "fake constructor" method LoadAsync() where the heavy lifting is done.

A viewmodel usually looks like this

```
public class MyVm : BaseViewModel {
    //... lots of fields and properties

    public MyVm(SubVm1 sub1, SubVm2 sub2, Repository1 repo1, SomeService svc){
         this.sub1 = sub1;
         this.sub2 = sub2;
         this.repo1 = repo1;
         this.svc = svc;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to decide whether i like this setup.

I thought about a ViewModelLocator, but then i cannot easily identify the dependencies of a class via constructor anymore. But i would be able to delay the object creation until the subVm is actually needed.

I thought about just injecting a factory method, keep the delay, keep the information. Easy to setup with autofac, but it looks strange to me.

It comes down to how expensive it is to instantiate those types of classes at startup. I read object creation is really cheap in C#, but is it still cheap, if i have a lot of fields and properties? What if we end up with 100s of viewmodels that all get created at the start of the application?

Comment: I like the MS way: Every VM has an InitializeAsync method and I call it when needed => https://github.com/microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps/blob/master/src/BikeSharing.Clients.Core/ViewModels/ViewModelBase.cs#L34

Comment: Another example https://github.com/SirRufo/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/Desktop/Desktop.WpfApp/App.xaml.cs#L68

Comment: Are your Models implementing `iNotifyPropertyChanged`? I've often found when profiling that if you have a lot of properties, the notification of everything changing during initialization can become expensive depending upon your structure.

Comment: Tronald, yes a lot of INotifyPropertyChanged properties. Are those firing at object creation though? I would not think so, but i dont know.

Comment: They may not be firing on initialization (depends on your constructors and how they are designed), but they are certainly firing when you populate the object. This issue normally presents when you start building large collections of the object. Are you working with collections as well?

Comment: Not really my question. I dont have a problem with the LoadAsync or InitializeAsync itself. Its still that way in all of my 3 approaches. What im wondering is about the potential 100s of classes that get instantiated at application start via autofac. I would essentially only use constructors for assignments. Like the one in my post. All initialization logic, no matter how simple, should go in LoadAsync cause why not.

Comment: It's not a performance problem until you measure and identify a performance problem.

Comment: Having said that, this is why I chose DryIOC for my container.  I wanted the fastest instantiation of objects possible.

Answer (score 0):

So at my job we have a C# wpf application. We have a startup sequence as follows:

- Init database (EF6)
- register all services
- Register all viewmodels

where viewmodels kan be nested.

Viewmodels consist of the construction of the viewmodel. In this approach, a viewmodel also constructs any children viewmodels, e.g. for datagrids, controls the likes of that.

Then we have a mechanism with prism where we have 2 handlers on each viewmodel for `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedAway` which get called when the user switches to or from a screen. In these functions, most of the update and cleanup logic resides. So the ctor would create a manager that interacts with the logic, and then only in our onNavigateTo we do the actual fetching of data.

Creating an object is extremely quick, and since we tend to keep the ctor away from long running functions (db calls etc) the most time by a factor of about 20 is actually the init of our services.

We create about 15 screens for modules, each with about 5-10 panels (so these are nested in our screen's viewmodels), which each could have about 1-10 controls. Then we have another 30 or so additional screens for other things.

So we have a fair bit of viewmodels, which can get fairly large, but because most resource intensive items are not located there, the load is quite small.

I don't know if this answers your question, but this should give you a better insight and i hope it helps.

In you case i would do the same. You can of course move to a more async way of things but i don't think the added complexity would be worth it. We optimize our services with async periodically if we measure that they take too long, startup takes a couple seconds and for both application and development this seems very okay.

Just remember; dont optimize before you measure and also make sure that you have a good idea of what is acceptable to the customer in terms of startup time.

Comment: Little off topic, but is your OnNavigatedTo method async? I would think it HAS to be, since you're fetching from the database. If it wasn't async, the UI would lock. We aren't actually doing any complex asynchronous stuff, we're just forced to use the async version of EF cores methods.

Comment: Nope all sync. most db calls (when implemented correctly) are a couple ms, so you don't even see it when switching screens. If it takes longer and you notice a screen delay (and that would be quite some data before getting there) we just implement some async behaviour in the viewmodel.